# Google Analytics - include filter not working

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, filtering

I just added an include filter this morning in my domain (`test.org`). I have:

*Custom Filter > Include > Request URI >* `^/test-a/46212$|^/test-a/46212|^/test-a/46315`

Now after I go to *Content > Site Content > All Pages*, I see stats for other pages that I didn't include in my filter. For example I see `/somethingelse`. I only want to see stats for `/test-a/46212` and whatever else in my filter.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Filters are not applied retrospectively so if you applied them this morning it would be too early to see the data filtered as of yet. To see the information for the past you could create a simple custom report.

Comment: I ended up adding a 2nd and 3rd filter. It seems to be working. We'll see.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment above - Filters are not applied retrospectively so if you applied them this morning it would be too early to see the data filtered as of yet. To see the information for the past you could create a simple custom report.