# Google Analytics include hostnames beyond character limit

Tags: google-analytics, filtering, google-analytics-spam

In an effort to prevent ghost spam, I am trying to filter traffic by hostname in Google Analytics. I have found several hostnames that appear legitimate, and now the length of these hostnames in regex exceeds the character limit in the Google Analytics filter field.

When I try to create two separate "include" filters (to cover all of these hostnames), they conflict with one another. As a result, my view doesn't register traffic from the set of the hostnames included in Filter 1.

1. Is there a way to "include" all of these hostnames regardless of the character limitation?
2. Is there a central repository of "safe" hostnames? I've got www.mysite.com, mysite.com, and subdomain.mysite.com. I've also added translate.googleusercontent.com|webcache.googleusercontent.com|web.archive.org|mysite.com.googleweblight.com|translate.baiducontent.com|
   mysite.us1.list-manage1.com|ww.mysite.com|www.mysite.toolweuse.com

Other sources I've already reviewed:

[Exclude multiple domains in Google Analytics](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/78513/exclude-multiple-domains-in-google-analytics)

[How to fight off Google Analytics referrer spammers?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/how-to-fight-off-google-analytics-referrer-spammers)

[Google Analytics - include filter not working](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/42789/google-analytics-include-filter-not-working)

Comment: So you are only trying to track referrals by a white list?    That would rule out seeing any new referrals, even from legitimate links.   Sounds like a poor way of hiding spam referrals to me.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I am using both referral exclude filters and hostname include filters. The referral filters are meant to block referral spam from known offenders who never hit the site. The hostname include filter is meant to accept traffic from legitimate hostnames. Sources that show this approach: https://moz.com/blog/stop-ghost-spam-in-google-analytics-with-one-filter https://www.ohow.co/removing-google-analytics-spam/ http://help.analyticsedge.com/spam-filter/definitive-guide-to-removing-google-analytics-spam/ Would love a better way (!) but want to  start by solving immediate question